# How to prepare Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to upgrade 14.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, backup

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 but I always fear losing my data. I never upgrade an Linux`s distro before, actually, this is about one year I am using it. 
So I don't know how actually this really works, when upgrading, but I want to keep my pictures, musics, documents and so on that are in my home folder. I launched Gparted and my partitions are:

```
1- /dev/sda1 File System: ext4 Mount Point: / Size: 690.78 Gib Used: 176.25 Gib Flags: boot
2- /dev/sda2 ~ ~: extended Mount Point: <nothing here> Size: 7.86 Gib Used: -  Flags: -
and inside /dev/sda2 there is an linux-swap with same size above.
```

My question is, how can I upgrade my 12.04 without losing my home files. I considered to create a partition to store it but I am not so sure. Also, after upgrading it, there is some way to re-install my old programs that were left in the old system? I mean, via Ubuntu Software Center?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You won't loose anything if you upgrade, all apps will stay installed and home and user profile untouched

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu supports in-place upgrades, and they're well tested.

To do an in-place upgrade from the command line all you need to do is `sudo do-release-upgrade` and follow the on-screen prompts.  New sources will be configured, new packages downloaded, and appropriate upgrade scripts run.  The process can take several hours, depending on the speed of your internet connection.

What you don't really want to do is just install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS over top of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, because the appropriate upgrades won't take place.